# Customizing TestNG result xml

Tags: testng

I am using TestNG to run my test suites and the tests are kicked off via Jenkins. I am using TestNG plugin in Jenkins. One of our requirement is to add a custom attribute called 'critical' to testng-results.xml

**Current testng-result.xml**

```
<testng-results skipped="0" failed="3" total="5" passed="2">
......
</testng-results>
```

**Expected testng-result.xml**

```
 <testng-results skipped="0" failed="3" total="5" passed="2" critical="2">
    ......
 </testng-results>
```

I tried below in @Test just to see how setAttribute works, but it didn't add any attribute to the test in testng-results.xml (not sure what I am missing, I am running TestNG programatically and not through command line). I am not sure if ITestResult.setAttribute would be useful in my case because I guess it will add attribute at the test level and I need to add attribute at the suite level. I also implemented `ITestListener` but wasn't successful. Am I missing anything, can someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit1**

**TestNGRunner Class** Running TestNG by code

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("Custom Report");     
XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setName("customreport");
classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
String [] runSuites = {"com.test.Testing"};
for(String asuite:runSuites)
  classes.add(new XmlClass(asuite));
test.setXmlClasses(classes);
List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
suites.add(suite);
TestNG tng = new TestNG();      
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);           
tng.run();
```

**com.test.Testing class**

```
@Test
public void test() {
  System.out.println("running my test");
  ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
  result.setAttribute("critical", 10);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call .getCurrentTestResult after the test, such as in the AfterTest annotated method?

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing these attributes in testng-results.xml, although they will be in a section of their own and not as an attribute of the `<testng-results>` tag.

Comment: I updated the question with my code. In testng-results.xml I still don't see the critical tag in testng-results.xml. I am using testng 6.5.1. Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set @Test (priority=0), Zero is having highest priority (or critical)